# Can I save serialized form data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, webforms, pagination

In my continued effort to understand hash tags and page navigation I'm hitting a road block with resubmitting form data if a user uses the browsers navigation buttons (e.g. back and forward).

My function that uses the form data is below:

```
if(page == "/visits_results") {

    $('#start').val(start);

    $.post("visits_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
    function(data) {
        $('#search_results').html(data);
        location.href = "#visits_results=" + start; 
    });
}
```

This works fine and dandy if the form is still visible, for instance if I use pagination it performs as I would expect.

My issue is when the user clicks the browsers back button (the form has now been removed) and then they click the browsers forward button.  The event gets triggered but my serialized form data is now empty.  Is there any way to cache the form data so I can continue to call it?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you thought about using swfaddress? http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save data fairly easily using [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Local_Storage) like http://jsfiddle.net/zDPjm/

Comment: window.localStorage.setItem seems like a logical solution but it isn't persistent. Any examples how I can set/get this as a cookie value? I'm thinking of the case when a user saves a URL and then tries to open it later on. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul, local storage is very persistent actually. As much so as a cookie. If you click back on the jsFiddle, you will notice the data is still saved.

Comment: @Paul, in addition, you are not as limited in size as you are with cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet (I think) would be to store the serialized data in a cookie. When the user returns to the page which he/she has already filled out, retrieve the data from the cookie, unserialize it, and place it back where it belongs.

Cookies are fairly trivial to work with, there is a decent cross-browser implementation for reading/writing cookies on quirksmode:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

or if you'd prefer to use a plugin:

- http://code.google.com/p/cookies/
- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Aww.  I thought I'd get to provide a good answer today.  This what I'd do as well Jquery doesn't persist between requests.

Comment: Can I use this in conjunction with window.localStorage.setItem?

Comment: You can, I guess, write a solution which uses localStorage where available and falls back to cookies where it is not available. It really depends on which browsers you want to support.

Comment: I really need to support IE 6+ , Chrome, FF, and Safari.  Is one method better then the other for this?

Comment: Then your best bet is probably cookies (or localStorage with cookies fallback). IE6, for instance, does *not* support HTML5.

Comment: well, I guess I should have done my research first.  Turns out 91.5% of my IE users are on versions 8 or 9 so I think I'll try the localStorage solution. It seems to do what I want and looks fairly straight forward.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Well, sure, you could do something very simple such as:

```
if ($("#profile_form_id").serialize() != "") serializedFormData = $("#profile_form_id").serialize();
$.post("visits_results.php", serializedFormData, /* Rest of Code */
```